# separation of month and year from database by using php

Tags: php, mysql

I was trying to get month and year from database when I click on the specific month from select option it should display month and as well as year, the result should fetch from database.
below is my code

```
<?php 
    $mon_arr=array("Jan"=>"01","Feb"=>"02","Mar"=>"03","Apr"=>"04","May"=>"05","Jun"=>"06","Jul"=>"07","Aug"=>"08","Sep"=>"09","Oct"=>"10","Nov"=>"11","Dec"=>"12");     
?>

        <select name="month" id="monthr">
        <?php foreach($mon_arr as $x=>$xval){ ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $xval; ?>" <?php if($m == $xval) echo "selected=selected"; ?>><?php echo $x; ?></option>
        <?php } ?>
        </select>
        <?php //echo $xval; ?>
        <?php //echo $m; ?>
        <?php //echo $x; ?>
        <select name="year" id="yearr">
        <?php for($yi=2014;$yi<=2025;$yi++){ ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $yi; ?>" <?php if($y == $yi) echo "selected=selected"; ?>><?php echo $yi; ?></option>
        <?php } ?>
        </select>
    </div>
    <table class="table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>#</th>
                <th>Description</th>
                <th>File</th>
                <th>Submitted By</th>
                <th>Date</th>
                <th></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <?php $sel_month=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM ".TABLE_MONTHLY." WHERE pid='".$_GET['pid']."' ORDER BY m_date DESC "); 
        $f=new all_calls();
                while($res_month=mysql_fetch_array($sel_month))
                {
        ?>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td><?php echo $res_month['m_desc']; ?></td>
                <td><?php $pathsi=explode(',',$res_month['m_file']); 
                for($ji=1;$ji<count($pathsi);$ji++) { 
                ?>
                <a href="<?php echo $pathsi[$ji]; ?>">Download</a><br />
                <?php
                }
                 ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $f->get_username($res_month['m_by']); ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $res_month['m_date']; ?></td>
                <td><a href="index.php?p=next&rel=mr&pid=<?php echo $_GET['pid']; ?>&mid=<?php echo $res_month['mid']; ?>&act=edit"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i></a></td>
            </tr>
            <?php } ?>
                       </tbody>
    </table>


<?php
class monthly_report{

function validate_and_insert($data,$mid,$mfile)
{

    //var_dump($mid); die;
    if(empty($data['mdesc'])) $err='Description Required';

    if(empty($err))
    {
        //echo 'hello'; die;
        //var_dump($mid); die;
        if(strlen($mid)==0)
        {
            $insert=mysql_query("INSERT INTO ".TABLE_MONTHLY." SET pid='".$_POST['hide_pid']."', m_desc='".$data['mdesc']."', m_file='".$mfile."', m_by='".$_SESSION['ID']."', m_date=CURDATE()");

            if($insert)
            {
                return 0;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            $a=new all_calls();

            $paths=$a->get_monthly_file($mid);

            if(strlen($mfile)==0)
            {
                $newfile=$paths;
            }
            else
            {
                $newfile=$paths.','.$mfile;
            }
            //var_dump($mid);die; 
            $update=mysql_query("UPDATE ".TABLE_MONTHLY." SET m_desc='".$data['mdesc']."', m_file='".$newfile."' WHERE mid='".$mid."' ");

            if($update)
            {
                return 0;
            }
        }
    }
}
}
?>
```

Can anyone help me out with this issue.

Comment: using ajax you can fetch result by selected month and  year. use onchange event for month and year, send request to another page. build result and return output, and finally display output $(".table").html(data). let me know if you want example code.

Comment: Don't use PHP's mysql_ API

Comment: yes it would be helpful if i get example code.